# Modify echo output

Tags: php

I am fetching some data from MySQL which I print into a table.  I have a function to "X out" the content after the first 2 up to the last 2 digits of a number.

Now I am trying to use that function on every number in the row 'code' where the MySQL result is `used=''` before printing it.

Example:  Data from mysql row 'code' and 'used':

> code = 123456789  & used = 'n' result=123456789
>   code = 123456789  & used = '' result=12XXXXX89

This is my code for fetching, creating the table and also for the function to "X out" the middle digits:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<?php function blankit($word) {
    return substr($word, 0,2). str_repeat("X",strlen($word)-4) . substr($word, strlen($word)-2,strlen($word));
} 
?>

<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ ?>
<tr class="first">
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['code']; ?></font></td>

<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['date']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['ip']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td> 


</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Did I really explain it that bad ? :-( .. I thought it's understandable. Anyways, MySQL table:  row1=code row2=used  - print row1 BUT if row2(used) is = '' then apply the function first otherwise just print row1(code)

Comment: `echo $rows['used'] == '' ? blankit($rows['code']) : $rows['code'];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what this "used" variable is since it's not shown in your code sample, but I'm guessing it's in your mysql result. Here you go:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<?php function blankit($word) {
    return substr($word, 0,2). str_repeat("X",strlen($word)-4) . substr($word, strlen($word)-2,strlen($word));
} 
?>

<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$code = ($rows['used'] == '') ? blankit($rows['code']) : $rows['code']; ?>
<tr class="first">
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $code; ?></font></td>

<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['date']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['ip']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td> 


</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thanks for understanding my poor description :-)

Comment: After implementing that, my table is not showing up at all anymore ?

Comment: Where is your "used" variable that you speak of. Maybe that is the problem. I was under the assumption it was in the $rows array.